# When to use DQL vs Methods and Loops

Tags: php, oop, symfony, doctrine, dql

When is it best to write a Doctrine query and when is it best to write methods for the object? This is what I perceive, but I'd like to get a more experienced opinion. I am trying to abide by good practice whenever possible.

### Doctrine Query:

Pros:

- fewer queries

Cons:

- Can't be written as a method in an object (not reusable)

### Writing a Method:

Pros:

- resusable

Cons:

- More Queries (lots of for loops)

Comment: what do you mean by writing a method? Can you give example? Do you mean finding like a a sum so write a query vs iterate over objects?

Comment: So my project has to do with Schools, so an example would be: I want to find the newest teacher in a school. There's a teacher table, a department table (many teachers to one department), and a school table (many departments to one school). Should I write a method in the School Class that loops through each department's teachers and finds the newest one or should i write a doctrine query that uses joins? Is that clearer?

Comment: If thats the case I would create a dql method in the teachers entity repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes wonder the same thing, however given your example I would add a method to your teachers [custom repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes). This way there is no cons, and it is also reusable

In other cases to help me decide I generally look at how many objects there potentially could be and how many sql statements doctrine is going to execute to do my lookup, if it is going to be a lot I will usually use DQL